# WebClient downloads an incomplete file

Tags: vb.net, webclient

This method that I wrote was working fine a week ago but now it downloads an incomplete file. The original file is nearly 10mb but the file that is being downloaded is 2k. My code is basically this

```
Dim URL as string = "http://www.cqc.org.uk/sites/default/files/cqc_locations_export.csv"
Dim path as string = "C:\temp"        
Dim webClient As New WebClient
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)")
webClient.DownloadFile(URL, path)
```

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is not my area, but you may be missing the size of the file, if it's binary, char encoding and other header data. Also, this 2k of file maybe a part of the file or metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The Second argument to `DownloadFile` requires a full filename not just a path (and the root of the `C:\` drive is protected on windows 7 so the method may throw an exception if you try to write here)

Note: Don't forget to dispose of the webclient when done.

Note 2: I would suggest you should avoid naming collisions by using names other than the .NET class names. Don't forget VB is case *insensitive* (unlike C#)

The following works fine for me:

```
Dim URL As String = "http://www.cqc.org.uk/sites/default/files/cqc_locations_export.csv"
Dim filename As String = "C:\temp\temp.csv"
Using wc As New WebClient
     wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)")
     wc.DownloadFile(URL, filename)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the site that is hosting the file, or how that site handles GET requests. I had the same problem downloading a URI I had shared from DropBox. The file was about 3 MB, but only about the first 112 KB was downloaded. When I downloaded the same file from Screencast.com, the whole file was downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

On ground you may want to try three things :

1. Run your application with Admin rights as C drive is protected in
   Windows 7 and above.
2. Temporary stop your antivirus program and try downloading again.
3. Only dispose webClient when download is complete (On DownloadFileCompleted Event)

Answer (score -1):

The docs seems to suggest either (two different variations)
Dim client As New WebClient()
or
Dim client As WebClient

Comment: @user1460625 Were both (my) options wrong? Or all three (or more) all correct?

Comment: Can you explain why you think one or the other would way make any difference to the issue posted?

Comment: Generally, with MS technology it is always best to follow their rules because you never know what beck-doors and side-effects the other options might have. If all options are correct then how can you guess what side-effects this may have.  
BTW: c:\temp may be a complete and valid file path too - where file named temp (with no extension) resides in C:\ root directory.